# Why do games suggest you take a break?

Tags: game-design

A lot of games will suggest you take breaks from them every 30 minutes or so, I think this is especially common in Nintendo games, but they aren't the only ones to do it. What is the advantage to this? Does this somehow help get you to play it more or does it help sell more copies?

Answer (score 9):

This generally isn't a reverse psychology tactic. The aim is actually to remind players how much time they've been spending in front of the screen and, in some cases, suggest that it might be time for a break.

This is because it can be [unhealthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_addiction) for a variety of reasons, to play games for extended periods of time, and the developers want to look out for their players.

There are far more effective techniques for getting people to play *more*. "You've been playing for..." reminders are generally somebody trying to do the right thing, or (from a more self-interested perspective) establish a defensive legal position, or to self-regulate in order to avoid the creation of [actual](https://www.engadget.com/2014/06/23/korea-debates-game-addiction-law/), legal, [regulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutdown_law).